# Pandas dataframe get unique value of a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unique

I'm trying to get the unique available value for each site. The original pandas dataframe is with three columns:

| Site | Available | Capacity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 7 | 20 |
| A | 7 | 20 |
| A | 8 | 20 |
| B | 15 | 35 |
| B | 15 | 35 |
| C | 12 | 25 |
| C | 12 | 25 |
| C | 11 | 25 |

and I want to get the unique available of each site. The desired table is like below:

| Site | Unique Available |
| --- | --- |
| A | 7 |
|  | 8 |
| B | 15 |
| C | 12 |
|  | 11 |

Comment: `df.drop('Capacity', 1).drop_duplicates()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the lists of unique available per site with `GroupBy.unique()`

```
>>> df.groupby('Site')['Available'].unique()
Site
A      [7, 8]
B        [15]
C    [12, 11]
Name: Available, dtype: object
```

Then with `explode()` you can expand these lists and with `reset_index()` get the index back to a column:

```
>>> df.groupby('Site')['Available'].unique().explode().reset_index()
  Site Available
0    A         7
1    A         8
2    B        15
3    C        12
4    C        11
```

Otherwise simply get both columns and remove duplicates:

```
>>> df[['Site', 'Available']].drop_duplicates()
  Site  Available
0    A          7
2    A          8
3    B         15
5    C         12
7    C         11
```

Comment: Thank you Cimbali. That's exactly what I want. I didn't know that 'unique' can be used after groupby command.

Answer (score 0):

Approach with: [`GroupBy.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) + [`Series.drop_duplicates()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html)

```
(df.groupby('Site')['Available']
   .apply(lambda s: s.drop_duplicates())
   .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
   .reset_index(name='Unique Available')
)
```

Result:

```
  Site  Unique Available
0    A                 7
1    A                 8
2    B                15
3    C                12
4    C                11
```